# Rails translate custom base error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

My models:

Product `has_many` variants `has_many` sizes

To sizes I add custom error, like this:

```
errors.add :base, "My custom error msg"
```

In the view I see: "Sizes base My custom error msg"

```
class Size < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  validate :custom_error, only: :update
  ...
  def custom_error
    errors.add :base, "My custom error msg"
  end
end
```

But how translate this message?

**UPDATED** I am found solution:

In locale.yml:

```
attributes:
  variants/sizes:
    base: ''
```

Comment: Can you show more code on how/where you're adding this error?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try:

```
errors.add :base, :custom_error
```

This should give you `translation missing` together with key name and a scope where this translation should be stored.

Update:

Just did it by myself:

```
translation missing: [locale].activerecord.errors.models.[model_name].attributes.base.custom_error
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked for second part of msg, but how translate first part **Sizes base** My custom error msg

Comment: Does your model defines `base` attribute? There should be no prefixes for errors on `:base`.

Comment: No I have not `base` attribute

Comment: What rails version are you using?

Comment: Thank you! I am updated my question and added answer.